# Find the smallest whole number..

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization

This question is related to prime factorisation.

How do I find the smallest whole number $b$ for which $240/b$ is a factor of $252$?

\begin{align*}
240 &= 2^4 \times 3 \times 5 \\
252 &= 2^2 \times 3^2 \times 7 \\
\end{align*}

Does the question mean the result from the division is a factor of 252? I'm a bit confused..

Comment: What is the highest common factor of $240$ and $252$?

Answer (score 2):

In answering this question we may query the *largest* factor of $240$ that is also a factor of $252$. Clearly, this is the GCD of the two numbers, which works out to be $2^2\cdot 3=12$ (using the prime factorisations given).

Since $12$ is the largest factor of $240$ that is also a factor of $252$, $240/12=20$ must be the smallest $b$ such that $240/b$ is a factor of $252$.

Answer (score 1):

find $gcd(240,252)$. it is equal to $12$. so $b = 240/12 = 20$

Comment: So b must be 12(is the smallest whole number) since both 240 and 252 is divisible by 12..... Am I right? Abit confused with the wording..

Comment: no b=20 ...  but we found the gcd to find that out.